# In a checkboxes list, make second "hiden" checkbox has the same check/uncheck state as first one and switch true/false state

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I have a list of checkboxes. For each one I have a hidden checkbox that needs to check/uncheck with the main.

So far I have this. The problem is that its an array but it catches only the first hidden checkbox. So for any main checkbox clicked only the first hidden one is affected. I struggle to make the js to apply for every pair of checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<label class="container">
<input type="checkbox" name="add_amenity[]" id="add-amenity" value="{$amenity.id_amenity}"/>{$amenity.name}<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" style="display:none" name="available_amenity_{$amenity.id_amenity}" id="available-amenity" value="1"/><span class="checkmark"></span>
```

JS

```
var chk1 = $("#add-amenity");
var chk2 = $("#available-amenity");

$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be __unique__

Comment: I tried to make them same as the name attribute but still doesn't work. I think I need some sort of a loop but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Could you post an HMTL example that contains the at least few input pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

If you can wrap both checkboxes into a wrapper, then you can use below method to achieve the goal.

```js
$(".checkbox_list input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

  var siblingEl = $(this).parents(".checkbox_list").find("input[type='checkbox']");

  if (this.checked) {
    siblingEl.prop("checked", true)
  } else {
    siblingEl.prop("checked", false)
  }
  
  console.log(siblingEl.is(':checked'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox_list">
  <label class="container">
<input type="checkbox"/>{$amenity.name}<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" /><span class="checkmark"></span>
</div>
<div class="checkbox_list">
  <label class="container">
<input type="checkbox" />{$amenity.name}<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="available_amenity_{$amenity.id_amenity}" /><span class="checkmark"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This changes the visually the checkboxes but doesn't change the values to true/false the hidden checkbox.

Comment: Checkboxes does not have values.

Comment: When I check the visible checkbox, it submits the values it has, in this case from 1 to 38. But the hidden one always defaults to 1. How can  the hidden one be **true** or **false** depending if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: You can use `.is(':checked')`

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect that? I really have very basic js understanding.

Comment: and avoid retracting your accepted answer for another question people here will stop replying to your questions

Comment: OK, thanks, It doesn't work for me and I spend like a day trying to figure this out. I guess it does what I asked for but it doesn't add to the db. It keeps adding 1. And I need 0 when false. Will try to figure things by myself.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But for anyone reading and wanting to improve or solve the case must find a way to submit the hidden property of 0/1 for the specific id and submit it individually to the db. Otherwise when inserted in the db it inserts 0 or 1 for all entries, not only for the one checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/** to toggele between two values **/
function selectHidden() {
  var el = $('#available-amenity')
  if (el.is(':checked') == true) {
    el.prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    el.prop("checked", true);
  }
}

/** To set as parent check box value **/
function selectHidden1() {
  $('#available-amenity-1').prop("checked", $('#add-amenity-1').is(':checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sample one
<br>
<label class="container">
<input type="checkbox" name="add_amenity[]" id="add-amenity" value="{$amenity.id_amenity}" onchange="selectHidden();" />{$amenity.name}<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="available_amenity_{$amenity.id_amenity}" id="available-amenity" value="1" /><span class="checkmark"></span>
<br><br>
<br> Sample two
<br>
<label class="container">
<input type="checkbox" name="add_amenity[]" id="add-amenity-1" value="{$amenity.id_amenity}" onchange="selectHidden1();" />{$amenity.name}<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="available_amenity_{$amenity.id_amenity}" id="available-amenity-1" value="1" /><span class="checkmark"></span>
```